# DHTMLX Scheduler Timeline new/existing entry issues

Tags: salesforce, visualforce, dhtmlx-scheduler

I have incorporated DHTMLX Scheduler within a Visualforce page for creating new appointments and maintaining existing appointments. I am facing a weird issue that occurs very randomly.

1. when I create a new appointment and click on a particular time, it jumps to the row above

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1ciR3yB0BTs8eNp0GOKxS8Fhvc6fSGMzc/view?usp=sharing

The same issue happens with the existing appointments:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/1Ucw3tee6CbtJ9BI36UZ2uszPC5Ft5jDK/view?usp=sharing

Any help would be helpful or please let me know if any other information is required.

Comment: Please check that all sections have unique key value in array.
If this doesn't help you to solve the issue - I need more info to reproduce. You can create topic on DHTMLX forum to get help faster.

Comment: Hi Polina,

Thanks for your reply. As this issue is very random, it sometimes happen and sometimes not. So there are no steps to reproduce it, it is just hit and trial. I will also create topic in DHTMLX. 

Thanks,
Vaishali

Comment: One more thing: if you change rows height (that calculated automaticaly) by CSS, it also can be a cause. For example, when you drag an event and Scheduler expect 10th row, but after redefining height it is 11th row - event jumps to the row above.